# HTTPS Get/ Post/Put/delete method in java

Tags: java

Please anyone help me. How to get HTTPs get/put/delete/post response in java.

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to do. Are you writing a java http client? Or you want to process these methods server-side.

Comment: yah i want to process thse methods in server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheme (http or https) doesn't matter for the code that handles it.

When you want to handle any of these methods in a servlet, declare a Servlet, and override `doGet(..)`, `doPut(..)`, `doDelete(..)` etc.

In order to enable https on the container you need to enable the SSL connector in `server.xml` and provide a certificate store. [See the SSL How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) (if using tomcat)

Comment: in client side wat shoud we do?

Comment: the client is the browser - nothing.

Comment: You could use Resty (Disclaimer: I'm the author of Resty). See http://beders.github.com/Resty   Other options: Apache HTTPClient, Jersey Client, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I took the advice of Jochen Bedersdorfer and used Resty. Its super easy and works well. Go for it!

beders.github.com/Resty